# How to to solve the responsiveness of mouseover and mouseout

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am sliding a div whenever there is a mouse over event and sliding it back(hiding) when there is mouse out event.
If I do too fast mouse out and mouse over, the div keeps oscillating. How do I fix this problem?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#in").ready(function(){    
     $("#out").mouseover(function () {
       $("#in").animate({"height":"toggle",},200);
     });
   });
   $("#in").ready(function(){    
     $("#out").mouseout(function () {
       $("#in").animate({"height":"toggle",},200);
     });
   });
 });
```

---

```
<div id="out"><img src="pics/1.gif" ><div id="in"><h1>Google</h1></div></div>
```

Comment: I think if you add a `.stop()` call before each animate it won't continue the current animation... `$("#in").stop().animate()...`

Comment: The problem is that the animation actually moved the element out of the mouse area firing a `mouseout` during the animation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method:

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```
$("#out").mouseover(function () {
     $("#in").stop(true, true).animate({"height":"toggle"},200);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should take the advice given by [me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487396/how-to-to-solve-the-responsiveness-of-mouseover-and-mouseout#comment15171667_11487396) and by [Raminson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11487415/558021).  The `stop()` function will halt all currently running animations on the given element and prevent the behavior you were seeing.

Another 2 things can be said about the code you posted.

1. You have a trailing comma in the parameters you gave to the `.animate()` function.
   `{"height":"toggle",}`.  Now that might work on Chrome and Firefox, but in IE that will probably not work and more over it probably won't tell you where **or** why it's not working.  You should never have trailing commas in an array or object in JavaScript....
2. You wrapped your jQuery call in the document ready handler (as you should) but then you wrapped your code within another ready handler for each element.`$("#in").ready()`... `$("#out").ready()`.   This is unnecessary.   You only need one ready function to make sure the DOM and jQuery are loaded.